# Why Matlab give me an uninitialized variable?

Tags: matlab, function, variables, indexing, arguments

At compilation, "epoch" was determined to be a variable and this
 variable is uninitialized.  "epoch" is also a function name and previous versions
 of MATLAB would have called the function.
 However, MATLAB 7 forbids the use of the same name in the same
 context as both a function and a variable.

```
function slope1_4=s(x,m)
A=xlsread(x);
slope1_4=[];
%B=xlsread(y);
%nbligneA=size(A,1);
%nbcolonneA=size(A,2);
%nbligneB=size(B,1);
%nbcolonneB=size(B,2);
for j=m %nbcolonneA
    clear ini;
    clear fin;
    ini=epoch(:,A(1,j),1);
    fin=epoch(:,A(1,j),2);
    ini(ini==0)=[];
    fin(fin==0)=[];
    for i=1:size(ini,1)
        clear f;
        clear a;
        clear b;
        clear y;
        debut=ini(i);
        ending=fin(i);
        interval=ending-debut+1;
        a=A(debut+1:ending+1,j);
        for y=1:interval
            f(y)=a(y);
        end
        y=1:interval;
        b=polyfit(y,f,1);
        slope1_4=[slope1_4,b(1)];
    end
end
```

The problem probably come from the ":" in epoch(:,A(1,j),1) but I don't know how to solve this problem..

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass `:` as an argument to a function. A [colon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html) is only valid as an index into a variable, so MATLAB assumes `epoch` is supposed to be a variable. However, you can't extract data from a variable you haven't initialized yet, hence the error you get.

Your function `epoch` expects an index (or range of indices) as the first argument. So you have to supply it with either a scalar index or a vector of indices of data that you want it to return. If you want it to return *all* the data (i.e. for *all possible* indices), but you don't know how big the data is when you call `epoch`, then you can pass a colon *string* as an argument, like this:

```
ini=epoch(':',A(1,j),1);
fin=epoch(':',A(1,j),2);
```

Comment: Here is my function epoch


    function epoch = untitled(epochn,car,inifin)
    load data.mat
    race = data.cit;
    for j=1:race.total_players
        for i=1:max(race.epoch_based_on_hyy(:,j))
            tempindex = find(i==race.epoch_based_on_hyy(:,j));
            epoch_intv(i,j,1) = tempindex(1);
            epoch_intv(i,j,2) = tempindex(end);
        end
    end
    epoch=epoch_intv(epochn,car,inifin);
    end

The input argument should be a number 1,2,3...

Comment: Thank you it's working,
I also found an other way, in my function instead of having
epoch=epoch_intv(epochn,car,inifin) I now have epoch_intv(:,car,inifin) and epoch is now a 2 variables function!